# Subtitles on VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, subtitle

I'm building a simple video player for an android device. This device is running android 4.2. I want to play a ts video with subtitles. 
I can play the video with the VideoView and I wonder if there is a way to show the subtitles. The subtitles are stored in the video file.

I've searched but I didn't find any answers. I've also tried with the ExoPlayer library but it doesn't play the video.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/JDaren/subtitleConverter). This basically takes SRT file as input and can produce XML output like this:

```
<p begin="00:02:46.696" end="00:02:48.228" >Burn them all!<br /></p>
```

so basically you need to add the jar to your android project, parse the srt file in advance (may be put in a `HashMap` where key is the start time and the value is the text), track in which position your video is being played and show the text on some text view.

Note: The library has some errors, basically Modify line 30 and 74 in `IOClass.java` and assign null in the lines.

If you want to test how the library works, compile it with `mvn package` and run it like `java -jar [jar-file][input.srt] SRT XML [output-xml]`

Basically you will have to modify a bit for android here and there, but in general its easy.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't have a srt file... The subtitles are internal in the video file